# Autojump on mac OS X returning path, but not jumping to desired directory

Tags: bash, terminal, osx-yosemite, iterm2

The problem I have on OS X Yosemite:

autojump v22.2.4 (https://github.com/joelthelion/autojump), via the alias

```
j
```

returns the path that I would like to jump to, but does not perform the actual jump.

The *sad* workaround is copying the returned path and adding it to a cd command.

```
j work   
/Users/peterlustig/Documents/workspace/
# now copy the resulting path manually
cd /Users/peterlustig/Documents/workspace/
```

The problem persists in both terminal and iterm2. I followed the post-installation instructions after

```
brew install autojump
```

and added

```
[[ -s $(brew --prefix)/etc/profile.d/autojump.sh ]] && . $(brew --prefix)/etc/profile.d/autojump.sh
```

to my ~/.bash_profile.

EDIT:

```
jc work
```

lets me jump to my 'workspace' directory (after printing the path to the workspace directory). 
Now, what is the problem with

```
j
```

?

Comment: just looking at the webpage do you have anything that modifies PROMPT_COMMAND?

Comment: not that I know of... would that be in ~/.bash_profile?

Comment: If you run `set -x; j work; set +x` what do you get as output?

Comment: output: + autojump work
/Users/peterlustig/Documents/workspace
+ set +x    // the problem remains, no jump is performed

Comment: Any solution? i got the same problem :(

Comment: Any solution found for this?

Comment: @ARK, MichaelMao has provided an answer that worked for me 7 years past the original question :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my issue is I did set j in my .bash_profile, after remove it did work

```
alias j='autojump'
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it working, I suggest you do the following:

1. Check which shell your running:

   ```
   ps -op $$

   # im runnning
   PID   TTY        TIME    CMD
   43977 ttys012    0:00.11 -bash
   ```
2. If you like me installed via `brew` then you probably added (there `.sh` files):

   ```
   [[ -s $(brew --prefix)/etc/profile.d/autojump.sh ]] && . $(brew --prefix)/etc/profile.d/autojump.sh
   ```

I'm running bash and was not aware there are different shells to include:

```
     # have a look in:
     /usr/local/etc

     # you should see mutliple shell scripts to include (depending on your env):
     autojump.bash -> ../Cellar/autojump/21.7.1/etc/autojump.bash
     autojump.sh -> ../Cellar/autojump/21.7.1/etc/autojump.sh
     autojump.zsh -> ../Cellar/autojump/21.7.1/etc/autojump.zsh
```

3. For me, there is no `/usr/local/etc/profile.d` only `/usr/local/etc`. Change the command to:

   ```
   # ~/.bash_profile
   # i append this as my last line, that seems to work
   [[ -s $(brew --prefix)/etc/autojump.bash ]] && . $(brew --prefix)/etc/autojump.bash
   ```
4. Logout of your Terminal and login, that should work.

Answer (score 1):

This helped me https://github.com/wting/autojump/issues/511#issuecomment-362142038:

You have to `cd <dirname>` first than autojump will remember it for you the next time you call `j <dirname>`

Answer (score 0):

It seems this bug exists in the latest version of autojump(22.5.1). autojump command just printouts the directory path, but does not changes the directory.

I did the following things -
1.) Added the following line to my ~/.zshrc file

```
[[ -s `brew --prefix`/etc/autojump.sh ]] && . `brew --prefix`/etc/autojump.sh
```

2.) Then simply created a alias which pipes the autojump to `cd`command

```
alias j=autojump | cd
```

Hope this works for you guys.

Answer (score -2):

I use bash on OSX. It was not working for me either. The problem was that I hadn't manually changed to any directories. Once I did that, it worked as advertised.